# React.js protect route with async authentication check

Tags: reactjs

I have a two routes in my React.js app: `/` with a login-form and `/panel` which should only be accessible of the user is authenticated.

Authentication is done by a JWT-token. The user is considered authenticated if the JWT-token is set as cookie and if the request to the Rest-API confirms the JWT-token.

This is the function I have made to check if the user is authenticated:

```
import Cookies from "js-cookie"
import axios from "axios"

const isAuthenticated = async () => {
    const authToken = Cookies.get("auth-token")

    console.log("auth " + authToken)

    if (authToken == null) {
        return false
    }

    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth`,
            {
                insecureHTTPParser: true,
            })

        if (response.status === 201) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return false
    }
}

export default isAuthenticated
```

I have a file `Routes.js` with my routes:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"

import isAuthenticated from "../utils/auth.js"

import Home from "../views/Home.js"
import Panel from "../views/Panel.js"



const ProtectedRoute = ({Component}) => {
    const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false) 
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true) 

    useEffect(() => {
        const checkAuth = async() => {
            if (await isAuthenticated) {
                console.log("Authenticated true")
                setIsAuth(true)
            } else {
                console.log("Authenticated false")
                setIsAuth(false)
            }

            setIsLoading(false)
        }

        checkAuth()
    }, [])

    /*
    if (isLoading) {
        return null
    }
    */

    console.log("isAuthenticated? " + isAuth)

    if (!isAuth) {
        return <Navigate to="/" replace />
    }

    return <Component />
}



const AppRouter = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/panel" element={<ProtectedRoute Component={Panel} />} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default AppRouter
```

The idea is that when the user is not authenticated he gets redirected to `/`. Otherwise the provided Component gets loaded: `<Route path="/panel" element={<ProtectedRoute Component={Panel} />} />`.

**The issue:** The check `if (!isAuth) {...}` gets executed before the function `checkAuth` had the chance to update the state. If I uncomment the `if (isLoaded) {...}` check, the panel always renders even if not authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

1. I used `if (await isAuthenticated)` which does not execute the function but just checks if the function `isAuthenticated` exists and is thus always true. Parentheses solved it `if (await isAuthenticated)`.
2. I had to add the JWT-Token in the Authorization-header in my `isAuthenticated` function.
3. The API returns 200 if authenticated and I checked for 201.